# Exchange 2010 send connectors on two domains

Tags: exchange-2010

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with Exchange 2010 and Forefront TMG.

Two domains are set to send and receive: *@xyz.com and *@dfs.com.

How do I configure the send connectors on Hub Transport? Must it be 2 send connectors or one? Some mails are not being delivered.

www.mxtoolbox.com shows this status:

```
OK - 212.184.xx.xxx resolves to mail.abc-defg.de, cde-abcd.de
    Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner
    Warning - Does not support TLS.
    0 seconds - Good on Connection time
    OK - Not an open relay.
    5.866 seconds - Warning on Transaction Time
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse DNS does not match SMTP banner needs to be resolved by changing the FQDN of the receive connector. Also check your external DNS reverse zone for a PTR record that relates to this FQDN.

Does not support TLS generally indicates that either the receive connector doesn't have TLS enabled (tick box) or, that it has a specific set of IPs that are 'allowed' and if this is the case you either need to add the IP of the server that will be connecting, OR, add a IP range of 0.0.0.0 > 255.255.255.255 for all servers to be able to connect.